# Reversing color ramp in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, symbology, color-ramp

I want to reverse the color ramp in ArcMap 10.2. In the example below, I want the red colour to be associated with lower values and the green color with the higher values.

Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Right click where the colour boxes are and select 'flip symbols'

Comment: could you please put your comment in the answer to mark it as an answer :)

Comment: It's not obvious how to do it. In that context menu there's also 'Properties for all symbols' which will allow you to change the outline colour (or no colour) for all your symbols, for example: by default it's 0.4 grey outline but sometimes you don't want an outline, instead of changing each one individually you can change them all to have no outline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To reverse the colour ramp applied to feature symbols:
[image]

Right click on the symbol column then from the context symbol select 'Flip Symbols'. Note that any specific changes made to a particular symbol will be overwritten by this action.